Microsoft Graph API using for external user
We have been working with the Microsoft Graph API to fetch the mail list of an external user using the following endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages. However, we are encountering an issue with the response returned by the API. The response is as follows:
stdClass Object ( [@odata.context] => https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('4e75df4a-021c-457d-a7b4-8bcabaae1cbb')/messages [value] => Array ( ) )
 

As you can see, the response does not include any list of mails. The value array is empty.
Could you please provide guidance on why this might be happening?
We allow API permission for mail read and enabled licenses in Microsoft 365.

Hi, Have you tried checking in the Graph Explorer or through Postman?

Yes , i tried with Graph Explorer but it ask for modify permission at time of Run Query and then get proper list of mail for external user. Here , how can i get that list via CRUL in my project.
